# Merge two images with GD Library, have 1 repeat in background

Tags: php, gd, imagecreatefrompng

I want to take an image that has transparency and then overlay that on top of a 60x60 (arbitrary size) image that repeats for the width and length of the first image...

So essentially use image 2 as a repeating background image that image 1 is on top of.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I used One Trick Pony's solution, but tried to modify it to create a square image out of a rectangle if the width is less than the height, but not stretch the original image and instead center it. I was able to center the image but then the repeating background does not continue repeating after the overlay image stops.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

    $overlay    = imagecreatefrompng('../images/' . $_REQUEST['overlay']);

    $repeating  = '../images/' . $_REQUEST['repeating'];
    $ext = explode('.', $_REQUEST['repeating']);
    $ext = strtolower($ext[1]);


    if ($ext == 'gif')
        $repeating  = imagecreatefromgif($repeating);
    elseif ($ext == 'png')
        $repeating  = imagecreatefrompng($repeating);
    elseif ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg')
        $repeating  = imagecreatefromjpeg($repeating);


    $w          = imagesx($overlay);
    $h          = imagesy($overlay);
    if ($w < $h) 
        $w = $h;

    $output = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagealphablending($output, true);


    imagesettile($output, $repeating);
    imagefill($output, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TILED);
    imagedestroy($repeating);    

    $offsetx = ($w - imagesx($overlay)) / 2;

    imagecopy($output, $overlay, $offsetx, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    imagedestroy($overlay);


    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($output);
    imagedestroy($output);



    ?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Overlay: `http://72.167.52.68/~viisi/ebaylist/images/back_test2.png`

Repeating: `http://72.167.52.68/~viisi/ebaylist/images/back_test.gif`

Expected result (but continue the repeating across the whole image): `http://72.167.52.68/~viisi/ebaylist/image/previewImage.php?overlay=back_test2.png&repeating=back_test.gif`

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, great idea - get active, write some code, post it here if you need help! I think PHP's GD-functions will be a good start.

Comment: I'm going to start on this tomorrow when I get back to the office, will post results once I have something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$overlay = imagecreatefrompng('/path/to/transparent/image.png');
$repeating = imagecreatefrompng('/path/to/repeating/image.png');

// create a new image matching overlay size
$w = imagesx($overlay);
$h = imagesy($overlay);
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagealphablending($output, true);
imagesavealpha($output, true);

// tile repeating image on it
imagesettile($output, $repeating);
imagefill($output, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TILED);
imagedestroy($repeating);    

// now add overlay on top
imagecopy($output, $overlay, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
imagedestroy($overlay);

// send to screen
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($output);
imagedestroy($output);
```

Comment: If you post the two images and another one with the expected output

Comment: It seems two of them are missing?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have changed them by accident. I put in the correct ones now.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be this block: `if ($w < $h) $w = $h;`  Any reason for that? Does the resulting image need to be square? If so, you should provide the real overlay image width to the copy function, not `$w` which you just modified: `imagecopy($output, $overlay, $offsetx, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($overlay), $h);`

Comment: It doesn't have to be square, but I would like to make the resulting image wider with the overlay centered.

Comment: Then like I said, just make sure you provide the correct coordinates to `imagecopy`. `$w` was incorrect because you made it take the size of the height, that's why you get the black area.